# jquery jSon method stucks when string contains quotes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

hi i tried lots of things to solve this but no solution for me my code is as below

```
$.ajax({  
          type: "POST",
          url: "../Controllers/webservice.asmx/InsertWPost",
          data: '{"a": "' + uname.val() + '","b" :"' + a + '","c":"' + b + '"}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {
                               msgbox.html(msg);
                               if (msg.d == 'a') {
                                         msgbox.html('Done');
                                     }
                                     else {
                                         msgbox.html('Error');
                                         alert(msg.d);
                                     }
                                 }
              });
```

Uname is a textbox it may contain quotes sometime but this code stucks when it contains double quotes if i change the quotes in code's data section then it stucks with single quotes, i tried parsejson that doesnt work too, i tried adding `'//"'+ uname.val()+'//"'`
that doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify - it will handle quotes and other things.  It is built into modern browsers but for older ones you can get an implementation [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

```
var data = {"a": uname.val(),
            "b": a,
            "c": b};
 ...
 data: JSON.stringify(data);
 ...
```